# Problems with titlesec, hyperref, biblatex and tocbibind

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, titlesec

I am using the `titlesec` package to change the section font to sans-serif. Unfortunately, this breaks the links to "unnumbered" sections both in the TOC and in the bookmarks sidebar of PDF readers. I am using the `tocbibind` package and the `heading=bibintoc` setting of `biblatex` to add both the bibliography and the list of figures to the TOC.

In the following example, only the link to "Section" works. Clicking on "List of Figures" jumps to the TOC instead, clicking on "References" jumps to "Section".

**foo.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sf,bf]{titlesec}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\addbibresource{foo.bib}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\clearpage

\listoffigures

\clearpage

\section{Section}

\clearpage

\nocite{foo}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

**foo.bib** (only needed because `biblatex` otherwise complains about an empty bibliography)

```
@book{foo,
author = {foo},
title = {foo}
}
```

Any way to fix this?

Comment: Does a `\phantomsection` in front of `\listoffigures` resolve your problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that there's a problem with `titlesec`; in this particular case, a possible solution is to use the [`sectsty`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) package instead; this will produce the correct links without having to manually add `\phantomsection` (after all, that's part of the role of `tocbibind`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\allsectionsfont{\sffamily\bfseries}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\listoffigures
\clearpage
\section{Section}
\clearpage
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `\phantomsection` in front of `\listoffigures` and `printbibliography`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sf,bf]{titlesec}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\addbibresource{foo.bib}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents\clearpage

\phantomsection
\listoffigures\clearpage

\section{Section}
\clearpage

\nocite{foo} \phantomsection
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

---

[`hyperref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) manual states:

> This sets an anchor at this location. It works similar to `\hypertarget{}{}` with an automatically chosen anchor name. Often it is used in conjunction with `\addcontentsline` for sectionlike things (index, bibliography, preface). `\addcontentsline` refers to the latest previous location where an anchor is set.

Comment: You should check that the link to the references, with your example, points to Section 1. Without `titlesec` all the links are correct without adding `\phantomsection`.